# Apply conditional restrictions in a range of a formula

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, range, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have to select the values for a chart, a range of values:

```
C7:K7
```

And I want to know if its possible to put a condition for the whole range, so when any value is some character it is considered as a `NA()`.

For example, we have:

```
'-       56       '-       78'5       12
```

And I want it to be treated like:

```
=NA()    56       =NA()    78'5       12
```

**EDIT TO CLARIFICATE:**

I want to use a formula in which some values of a range are treated like another value that its original. This is because I have some values that are considered 0 (`'-`) and I want to keep those values but indicate in the formula that those values have to be treated like `=NA()`.

Comment: Do you want to find the values `'-` and replace them with `=NOD()` formula?

Comment: @glh No. I want to keep those values in the cells, but use a formula in which thos characters are replaced with `=NOD`. Something like `=IF(C7:K7="'-";=NOD();C7:K7)`

Comment: I have a simple method for overriding below but I am unsure what you are after unless you are able to create a dummy sheet to reference these cells?

Comment: also what is `nod()` is this the Spanish function to get `#N/A`? If so English is `=NA()`

Comment: @glh Oh, sorry, You're right. Edited

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd best create another sheet that references these cells using the following example formula for cel `A1` and use this new range to chart off:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="'-",NA(),Sheet1!A1)
```

I'm not entirely sure if this can be done through the chart builder / data property itself...